# pandas groupby vs. pyspark groupby not the same

Tags: python, dataset, pandas-groupby, apache-spark-sql

I have pandas dataframe and I've already performed a groupby. Now I'm changing the process and using pyspark.

The groupby in pandas and pyspark is different (the row count).

Has anyone experienced this?

Comment: I have encountered this but it was not a problem with `groupby` but some other manipulation I was doing previous. I think many call this 'code smell'. To check I would take a look to see which rows appear to be lost from the spark dataframe to the pandas, and see if that leads to any new information.

Comment: @JosephPNardone, it turns out pysark (me) was calculating week number differently to pandas. Changing the configuration of this (how week number is calculated) fixed the so called ''groupby'' problem.

Comment: Great Hamesh, if you would kindly upvote my comment I would appreciate it as a moderator deleted my answer and converted it to a comment.